# Does anyone know any sample for this question

Tags: database-design, erd

I need to create a project that has this kind of request on school but I have no idea how to start, has anyone any samples or anything for help:

> To compile a database request for a system, the request must be compiled in that form that the design of the conceptual model ie the diagram of ER (entity relations) to result in components as well as:
>
> - Simple attributes, key attribute / deskreminator, compound / multiplier, derivative attribute
>     and descriptive attribute.
> - Strong and weak entities community
> - Participation of entity communities in the community of relationships (full / total participation
>     and partial participation.
> - Relationship Stairs; uni-are, binary, trine.
> - Cardinality of reflections between entities such as one-on-one, one-to-many, many-with-many,
> - Entity Combinations for Conception of Design:
>
>   - downstream generalization, l
>   - golden-down specialization and
>   - Abstraction of entities in accumulation
> - Design cases where the community of entities can be used against the attributes of the community
>     entities against the community of relations, the community of n-are relations with binary ones.
> - 1) Compile the text (request) for the implementation of an IT system database.
> - 2) Design ERD for the above-noted request. (Note: Use any platform to design
>     ER-D)
> - 3) The final model obtained from point 2, convert to relational model (Note: use any platform
>     to design the relational / tabular model)

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Comment: Please read & act on [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Right now you are just asking us to rewrite your textbook & give a bespoke tutorial & do your homework--that is too broad a question. Give the name & edition of your published academic textbook. Show your work following it. Quote definitions, theorems & algorithms you are using. The first place you are stuck explain about why. (Don't just give some milestones. Without your reasoning we can't tell you where you went wrong or right & we have to redo your reasoning instead of just checking it.)

Answer (score 0):

The steps involved in making an ER diagram are:

1)You must decide which of the following objects in your system would be entities      and what would be the describing features(attributes) of those entities, keeping in mind the unique attribute of the entity which would be the primary key.
For example in an IT system database, you could have clients as an entity with various attributes of these clients.

2) Decide the weak entities which don't have a primary key and which strong entities these weak entities depend on. Decide the discriminator of these weak entities.

3) Decide the relationship between various entities keeping in mind the cardinality.

4) You may have specialisations which could be disjoint or not.

[For more read here](https://creately.com/blog/diagrams/er-diagrams-tutorial/)

After this draw the schema of the ER eliminating the redundancies and normalising the tables accordingly. Finally go on to making your tables in SQL.